# Volley ClientError on Video Upload Post Request

Tags: android, django, android-volley

I am trying to upload video from android to Django server. I am able to upload bitmap but when comes to video mp4 upload the code is causing errors.

I am getting this error 'com.android.volley.ClientError' after calling the following function uploadMP4. Though, the same code works very well on uploading bitmap but on uploading video the same code is causing errors.

Please Help. Thanks.

```
       private void uploadMP4(final Uri videoUri, final String ext) {
    
            if (selected_item_id == null) {
               // return;
            }
    
            String URL = "http://" + getIP() + "/inventory_apis/uploadMP4File";
    
            VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
    
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("GotError", "" + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }) {
    
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    
                    params.put("clubbed_item_id", selected_item_id);
                    return params;
                }
    
                @Override
                protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                    Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                    long filename = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    params.put("video", new DataPart(filename + ".mp4", getFileDataFromDrawable(getApplicationContext(), videoUri), selected_item_id));
    
                    return params;
                }
    
            };
    
            //adding the request to volley
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);
        }
    
    public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Context context, Uri uri) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                InputStream iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                int bufferSize = 1024 * 10;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    
                int len = 0;
                if (iStream != null) {
                    while ((len = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
```

The following details of Stack Trace

```
2021-12-20 20:46:55.461 1563-1563/com.example.skybot D/GotError2: com.android.volley.ClientError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:190)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

Comment: Hello! I think you'll need to provide a stack trace or something for anyone to be able to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting the question in hurry. The issue isn't on the above code but the code on the server-side where I used user login authorization. I removed the user auth and added my separate token algo code and the above code worked fine.

Issue Resolved. Thanks for the help.